# How to add charset to Content-Type in my output main.css file

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, content-type, charset

I have a problem how to add charset to my output file css file in ReactJs.

I tried using @charset "UTF-8", but it does not affect the Content-type of the file on the network.

I don't know what I could adjust to change this.

[My network console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2wcX.png)